# How to compose the Android Equivalent of a custom JPanel (AKA View)

Tags: java, android, swing, user-interface

I am trying to create a really involved UI for integrating with a proprietary product (it's currently web based and a total hack). Each screen/view has the same look-and-feel, the same 2-3 buttons in the same locations on every page. It's just 1 portion of that display changes.

If this were swing I would define a JPanel, compose everything but this center component, and then create instances of said panel Supplying the differing fields per instance.

I want to represent the 90% common portions of this UI flow as a single view and just fill in some blanks.

Can I do that? How do I do that? No haters please. Total Android rookie (seasoned Java vet though)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do that?

Sure! However, I wouldn't describe it as a "total Android rookie" sort of problem, just as it wouldn't be a "total Swing rookie" sort of problem in that environment.

> How do I do that?

There are a few possible approaches. The simplest solution is to define a layout resource file that defines the entire UI, with a `FrameLayout` as the placeholder where "some blanks" will eventually go. Then, at runtime, when you use that layout, you would "fill in the blanks", by putting something into that `FrameLayout`:

- If you want each "screen/view" to be an `Activity`, you would use the aforementioned layout file in `setContentView()`, then manually inflate (or instantiate directly in Java) whatever "some blanks" are. You would call `addView()` on the `FrameLayout` to "fill in the blanks" with whatever you inflated. If you wanted, most of the logic could be bundled up in a base class, with subclasses overriding some `gimmeTheBlanksPlease()` method that supplies what is to be poured into the `FrameLayout`.
- If you want each "screen/view" to be a `Fragment`, you would use the aforementioned layout file in `onCreateView()`, then manually inflate (or instantiate directly in Java) whatever "some blanks" are. Again, you would pour that stuff into the `FrameLayout` via `addView()`, and once again most of this codde could be implemented in an abstract base class.

There are more complex solutions (e.g., custom `ViewGroup`) as well.

The only simpler solution is *if* the "90% common portions of this UI flow" can be defined in ~1 layout file, you can use the `<include>` tag for composition of layouts. You'd have one common layout with the common elements, which would be included into the per "screen/view" layout and used at runtime. Again, you'd probably have an abstract base `Activity` or `Fragment` that knew about the common stuff. However, this gets messy if the "90%" would wind up being split among a whole bunch of layout files, just because of how the XML and positioning worked.